# WP query posts pagination doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

After addig a `query_posts` code to my WP template index.php file my pagination is not working anymore. I did use search and tried a few methods but nothing seems to work for me.

All I did was to add the line `<?php if ( is_home() ) {query_posts( 'cat=-85' );}?>` to this code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area clr">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
            <div class="container clr">
                <div id="post" class="col col-1 span_3_of_4 clr">

                    <?php if ( is_home() ) {query_posts( 'cat=-85' );}?>
                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php wpex_pagination(); ?>
                </div><!-- #post -->     
                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            </div><!-- #post -->
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: you can use this one http://blog2knowledge.com/how-to-add-pagination-in-your-wordpress-blog-without-plugin/

Comment: I already have pagination on the site but as soon as I add that line of code it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Just a side note: You don't need to use so many PHP tags. That is, rather than wrapping individual lines, wrap blocks of code, and only leave the code PHP block when you're putting in non-PHP code. For example, here, all the code inside the innermost `<div>` could be a single block.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution:

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) {
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-85&paged='.$paged);
} ?>
```